# iPhone Call handling within application

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to get the number from the incoming call, so that I can set the preference for an individual number. For instance, I want my cell to only ring if my Mom is calling otherwise leave it in vibrate mode.

Is there a method to get the number while call state is changed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681449/how-to-get-user-incoming-call-phone-number-in-ios-device

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to implement this functionality at the moment. Apple do not provide access to the phone call. If there is an incoming call, your app goes to background. If you want to make a call from the app - you can do it with a URL and your app again goes to background.