# Get number of incoming Phone call IOS device

Tags: ios, callkit

I am trying to get the caller number of incoming Phone call , on an IOS device. I managed to get notification on the event of incoming call by using 
CXCallObserver of CallKit , but I can not find how to get the Phone number of the caller. I searched a lot and it seams that the data of the Phone number is considered private by Apple. Is there away to extract the phone number of incoming call?
If there is not, then how TrueCaller are able to recognize people (on IOS) that are NOT on the phone contact list, they must get the incoming call number in order to search in their Users DB ( I am taking about the feature of call recognition, not spam recognition. Spam recognition is using a local DB of spam numbers which does not require the extraction of incoming call number)

Any help will be appreciated, I searched a lot and can not find an answer, but I am sure that if TrueCaller can do it, it is possible.

In this thread:
[How to get user incoming call phone number in iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681449/how-to-get-user-incoming-call-phone-number-in-ios-device) 
They talk about similar subject but only regarding the spam function of true TrueCaller which is not really equivalent because as I said before Phone call recognition logic is different then spam recognition.

Comment: You can't get the incoming phone number.  TrueCaller and similar apps register known numbers and names with iOS via CallKit so that a name can be displayed when that number calls.  TrueCaller can only get the called number if the user chooses to share it with the app when reporting a new spammer.

Comment: Do you mean that true caller created Action extension, like described in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161222/get-the-callers-phone-number-from-an-incoming-call-on-iphone

Comment: According to TrueCaller description of "live caller ID notification"  : "If you’re a Truecaller user using an iPhone, and you receive a phone call from another Truecaller user (whether they’re a contact of yours or not), you’ll get a live Caller ID notice on your phone" .  https://support.truecaller.com/hc/en-us/articles/212655445-How-does-Caller-ID-on-iOS-work-

Comment: So According to what you say , they need to register the entire  user DB (huge amount of records) into the local device in order to display ID for phone call which is not in the contact list of the device. I am note sure that this is how they work

Comment: That is what they have to do; An app cannot access the incoming number for privacy reasons.  An app can provide a CallKit identification extension that publishes numbers and names into the iOS caller ID database.  Callkit extensions simply have to provide the number as an Int64 and a name to go with it.  It isn't that much data.  Since iOS simply needs to identify the number from a sorted list of Int64 it can do so very quickly and efficiently

Comment: You can tell this is what TrueCaller does because they appear in Settings under Call identification plug ins

Comment: I think they use call identification only for "recognized spam" feature. They even say in their site that when doing IOS to IOS call the caller must initiate the call for inside TrueCaller app (probably because then, they can  have the destination call number, and they can create push notification from the caller to the destination via a server) so if the caller uses the default dialed they have no ability to recognize the call.

Comment: So it seams to me that your theory is wrong, if they were loading their entire DB to the local device, they would need to have the constrain of initiating the call from the app on IOS  . please see https://support.truecaller.com/hc/en-us/articles/212655885-Why-is-Caller-ID-on-iOS-limited-to-incoming-calls-from-other-Truecaller-users-

Comment: Yes, it seems that that is a new feature they have added. Regardless, it doesn't change the answer to your question; you cannot get the number of the caller in your app.

Comment: They probably use push notification from the caller to the destination via server. please see: https://7labs.io/mobile/how-truecaller-works.html